# live preview web application

Tags: java

I'm developing a web application and I need to provide a feature where the user can do some modification to his profile and preview it. If he doesn't like it, he just cancel it. If he like it, he submit the changes.

I was wondering if there is a design pattern to do that or if I just need to handle everything on the client side without giving it too much thinking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be very frustrating for a user to have to wait for client-server request-responses to be able to see a live preview of data.

Such functionality is usually done with JavaScript on the client side. Some JS frameworks (like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)) offer two-way binding for your form input data (or any other html element) and the backing JavaScript model. That makes it easy to provide that functionality.

You could for example bind the JS model to both the form input and profile display. As you are typing, the profile changes will be instantly shown.